# Error when running auto-sklearn: "couldn't close file"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I try to run "automl.fit" I encounter this error. I ended the process of training early once by clicking the red square in Spyder. Now, for some reason, every time I try and run this code snippet (with any data), the following error pops up in bold, followed by a continual stream of [ERROR] cannot recover some sort of files.

**libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Couldn't close file**

[ERROR] [2021-05-05 16:17:53,141:Client-pynisher] Cannot recover the output from /var/folders/kn/z3ymwsvj46z6hx2t8rpxmyt40000gn/T/tmpobk5b33h/std.err due to [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/kn/z3ymwsvj46z6hx2t8rpxmyt40000gn/T/tmpobk5b33h/std.err'
Process ForkProcess-1:

```
import autosklearn.regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X_normalized,y_normalized,random_state=0)

automl = autosklearn.regression.AutoSklearnRegressor(
    time_left_for_this_task=120,
    per_run_time_limit=30,
    tmp_folder='/tmp/pleasework_tmp',
    output_folder='/tmp/pleasework_out',
)
automl.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I have rebooted my computer, reset kernels for spyder/python, tried to uninstall auto-sklearn (but the error pops up again when I try to uninstall it).

(1) Is there any way I can delete this package directly from my file explorer? If so, how do I find where the all folders associated with the package is located and safely delete?

(2) Can I find where any temporary files "tmp" files are saved for auto-sklearn and delete them? If so, how do I find them?

(3) any other suggestions?

For some background if it helps, I'm running on a MacBook Pro, macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you run a command that used **sudo** to install packages, e.g.: `sudo pip install auto-sklearn`? This looks like a problem where packages were installed to a directory with administrator privileges. The easiest way to solve would probably be with virtual environments ([venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) or [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)).

Comment: Hi thanks Alexander! I don't remember using "sudo" to install - I just used "pip install ...". However, I created a new environment, redownloaded all the packages, and that worked! Thank you so so much!

I think it was scikit learn getting stuck in some loop (from me maybe terminating the program early?) where it kept trying to close or reference some temporary files... Can't figure exactly out what happened but the new environment is working great. Cheers!